# Xiaomi's GetApps Console says "The package name does not match, please upload the Apk file with the same name as the created package". They are same."

Tags: android, upload, apk, xiaomi

Trying to upload an apk to the Xiaomi app store and Xiaomi's GetApps Console says "The package name does not match, please upload the Apk file with the same name as the created package".
But they ARE the same. Been at this for a long time. Anyone uploaded to these guys before? Is there something about this I'm missing here? Package name is com.example.myApp and apk is com.example.myApp.apk

Tried uploading the same apk that other app stores were fine with.
Result: GetApps Console says "The package name does not match, please upload the Apk file with the same name as the created package"
I tried making an apk for them with a modified gradle build file that made sure package name and apk name were the same.
Result: Same error message.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the `.apk` extension to make in really identical? If you are on Windows make sure file extensions are not hidden in Windows explorer settings.

Comment: I tried it. No luck. File extensions are not hidden.

Comment: The file name is not the package name. Drag the apk into Android Studio and check the actual package name.

Comment: The package name is com.example.myApp.

Comment: This has been confirmed through Android Studio, Google Play, and other sources. The apk filename is com.example.myApp.apk . They match. And yet.... error: "The package name does not match, please upload the Apk file with the same name as the created package"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had the same issue, I found the solution.
1 of all you should know your package name - as u said u have it "com.example.myApp" (u can check it into AndroidMainfest.xml (reactNative) package="xxx.xxxxx.xxxx"

2 When u create the App into Mi developer Console (https://global.developer.mi.com). Here you need to fill 3 fields:

- Default language* choose what u want
- Package name* - should be the same is from AndroidMainfest.xml, for you example its "com.example.myApp"
- App Name* - fill what u want

3 optional, but i renamed .apk file to the same as package name "com.example.myApp.apk" - but dont thin so its necessary :)

4 and try to upload this .apk into "App release" tab

I think it will help you

Comment: **dryusha87's answer is correct!** I never would have figured that out without your help. Those are the first three fields you fill in when you "create" an app in the xiaomi store and "package name" is neither available to edit nor visible to check after that. I had to create a new app and then the upload went smoothly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your app name should be app name that will be visible to others.
Package name should be the same that you submitted should be exactly the same package in your project:
Project:
com.example.app
Xiaomi :
com.example.app
Hope that helps